# The useContext renders all the redundant components that are subscribed to it

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using contextAPI to store data of the react app like states, functions, variables, objects and arrays.

I am storing everything in an organized way like I am creating a component object and storing it's relevant data into that.

This is my reducer function.
You can see how I am storing data in the context.

```
const globalDataReducer = (state, action) => {

switch (action.type) {

case STORE_IN_GLOBAL_DATA:


const { component, typeOfData, data: newData } = action.payload;

if (!state[component]) {
state[component] = {};
}

if (!state[component][typeOfData]) {
state[component][typeOfData] = {};
}

return {
...state,
[component]: {
...state[component], [typeOfData]: {
...state[component][typeOfData], ...newData
},
},
triggered: component
}

default:
return state;
}
};
```

And, below is my action creator for the reducer.

```
import { STORE_IN_GLOBAL_DATA, INVALID_TYPE_OF_DATA } from "./action.types";

const storeInGlobalData = (data, typeOfData, component) => {

let actionType = INVALID_TYPE_OF_DATA;

const dataAllowed = ["states", "nodes", "objects", "arrays", "refVars", "vars"];

if (typeof data === "object" && typeof typeOfData === "string" && typeof component === "string") {
for (let data of dataAllowed) {
if (data === typeOfData) {
actionType = STORE_IN_GLOBAL_DATA;
break;
}
}
}

return {
type: actionType,
payload: {
component,
typeOfData,
data
}
}
};

export { storeInGlobalData };
```

So, the problem is arising that whenever I try to get the data using useContext, it renders all the components which are subscribed to the context. This reduces performance and causes ill effects in the app.

As you can see in my reducer code I am using the triggered property to know which component got triggered when.

I thought that by using the triggered property I will only render the component that is triggered by using the general 'if' conditions, but, I failed in doing so, as react says you can't apply conditions and what so ever. So, this approach failed.

So, my question is,

1. How could I control the redundant rendering? I just want to render that component that is triggered.
2. I noticed whenever we use the useContext or useSelector (in redux case) hook it renders the component before the normal renders happen, due to which it renders twice. Can we control this too and make it happen once only?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design any component that uses your context rerenders. This is how React works. To be able to get rid of the unnecessary renders you should split your big context into multiple contexts and use them only in the components that really need it.

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156) is a more detailed explanation done by Dan Bramov.

Comment: Yes, your approach is the right one.

I figured out the way for my above-shown context and it can be made to work, but it needs a lot of work around and is not performance friendly.

Splitting context removes a lot of hassle and is performance friendly as well.